# SSIS: Dynamically Toggle OLE DB Destination error output btw "Fail component" and "Redirect row" with expression/variable

Tags: sql, redirect, ssis

Is it possible to change the Error Output of an OLE DB Destination between "Fail component" and "Redirect row" at run time using an expression/variable?

One of the ways I debug my packages is by redirecting error rows in the data flow to a **Row Count** transformation, then adding a data viewer to display the row throwing the error, the record number, and error code/column so I can see the actual value of the column that is causing the error and know where it is located in the data file.

The problem is, when setting up a new package, sometimes there can be many errors on several different columns and I'm looking for a faster easier way to toggle this on and off.

If not expressions/variables, is there a way to do this programmatically?

Thank you for any help you can provide,

CTB

Answer (score 0):

These properties are not exposed that you would be able to set them with an expression or variable.  The fastest way to set them, especially if you have lots of columns, would be to update the package xml.  In the solution explorer, right click your package and go to view code.  In the XML, do a find for: errorRowDisposition="FailComponent"
and replace with: errorRowDisposition="RedirectRow"

Also, you can use a derived column instead of a rowcount so that you do not have to actually modify the component (create and set the variable for the row count so that it validates).